# how can i convert my data in javascript server side to json object and array?

Tags: javascript, json, xpages

i'm working with xpages and javascript server side i want to convert the fields in format json then i parse this dat and i put them in a grid,the problem is that these fields can contains values :one item or a list  how can i convert them in json ?
this is my code :

```
this.getWFLog = function ()
    {
        var wfLoglines = [];
        var line = "";

        if (this.doc.hasItem (WF.LogActivityPS) == false) then 
            return ("");

        var WFLogActivityPS  = this.doc.getItem ("WF.LogActivityPS"); 
        var WFActivityInPS   = this.doc.getItem ("WFActivityInPS");
        var WFActivityOutPS  = this.doc.getItem ("WFActivityOutPS");
        var WFLogDecisionPS = this.doc.getItem ("WF.LogDecisionPS");
        var WFLogSubmitterPS = this.doc.getItem ("WF.LogSubmitterPS");
        var WFLogCommentPS      = this.doc.getItem ("WF.LogCommentPS");
        var WFLogActivityDescPS = this.doc.getItem ("WF.LogActivityDescPS");
        var Durr =((WFActivityOutPS-WFActivityInPS)/3600);
        var json= {
                    "unid":"aa",
                    "Act":WFLogActivityPS,
                    "Fin":WFActivityOutPS,
                    "Durr":Durr,
                    "Decision":WFLogDecisionPS,
                    "Interv":WFLogSubmitterPS,
                    "Instruction":WFLogActivityDescPS, 
                    "Comment":WFLogCommentPS
            }




        /*
         * 
         * var wfdoc = new PSWorkflowDoc (document1, this);
histopry = wfdoc.getWFLog();
var getContact = JSON.parse(histopry );
 */ }
```

Comment: probably you should use getItem**Value** and take care about multivalue fields

Answer (score 1):

Careful. Your code is bleeding memory. Each Notes object you create (like the items) needs to be recycled after use calling `.recycle()`.

There are a few ways you can go about it. The most radical would be to deploy the OpenNTF Domino API (ODA) which provides a handy `document.toJson()` function.

Less radical: create a helper bean and put code inside there. I would call a method with the document and an array of field names as parameter. This will allow you to loop through it.

Use the Json helper methods found in com.ibm.commons.util.io.json they will make sure all escaping is done properly. You need to decide if you really want arrays and objects mixed - especially if the same field can be one or the other in different documents. If you want them flat use `item.getText();` otherwise use `item.getValues()` There's a good article by Jesse explaining more on [JSON in XPages](https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/EF0B875453B3CFC285257D570072F78F). Go check it out. Hope that helps.

Comment: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json is very useful, I use it extensively in REST plugins. However, just be aware that the version available with 9.0.1 up to FP7 doesn't properly handle timezones when converting date/times. If the server timezone is what youo want, it's fine. (I haven't checked since FP8)

Comment: I usually use Google's GSON (also used in Verse on premises).

Comment: Yes, GSON and Jackson are both very useful. GSON is used by Watson Work Services Java SDK. In my case I was iterating through views, so creating JavaJsonObjects directly rather than Java objects first.

Comment: In VoP I also directly create json output with gson. It takes care of commata, escaping and encoding

Answer (score 0):

If an input field contains several values that you want to transform into an array, use the `split` method :

```
var WFLogActivityPS = this.doc.getItem("WF.LogActivityPS").split(",")
// input : A,B,C --> result :["A","B","C"]
```